# Query navigation property from view with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, view, entity-framework-core

I am having a data model where persons can be assigned to a task over time and a task. The model looks basically like this:

```cs
class Task {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<TaskAssignment> TaskHistory { get; set; }
}
class Person {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<TaskAssignment> TaskHistory { get; set; }    
}
class TaskAssignment {
    public int TaskId {get;set;}
    public Task Task {get;set;}

    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public Person Person {get;set;}

    public DateTime AssignedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UnassignedAt { get; set; }
}
```

As people can be assigned and unassigned a person and task can always have a list of "current" assignments (notice the nullable `UnassignedAt`). What I would like to do is to add a navigation property to my models which only contain the "active" assignments (`where UnassignedAt == null`).

To do this I thought of adding a database view "CurrentTaskAssignments" where I do the filtering to rows having `UnassignedAt` unset. If I extend my models like this:

```cs
class Task {
    public virtual ICollection<TaskAssignment> CurrentAssignments { get; set; }
}
class Person {
    public virtual ICollection<TaskAssignment> CurrentAssignments { get; set; }
}
```

Can I make Entity Framework Core somehow make the queries for those navigation properties on the view? The queries would look like this:

```cs
// query tasks including the current assigned 
db.Tasks.Include( t => t.CurrentAssignments ); // join on view
// query tasks including the whole history
db.Tasks.Include( t => t.TaskHistory); // join on normal table
// query the currently assigned persons for a task
db.Tasks.Where(t=>t.Id == 3).SelectMany( t => t.CurrentAssignments.Person ); // join on view with join to person
```

Ultimately this will be exposed via a OData API. Thats why I'd like to realize this fully on EF level recycling the existing entities to leverage object expansion and filtering capabilities.

I saw that there are Query Types available as feature, but I would like to prevent defining a new duplicate Entity class for the View that returns an already existing entity.